# The namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'Workflow'

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamic-programming, workflow-activity

I'm working on a Custom workflow activity.  I've created my own helper.cs (Early Bound Entity Classes) with the Code Generation Tool (CrmSvcUtil.exe)

When I try to compile the code, it returns the following error:

> The namespace '' already contains a definition for 'Workflow'

From the Helper.cs file.

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: yes, "don't use generic names already taken by CRM".  However, Dragos' solution would also work.

Comment: Try this solution " Restart Omnisharp" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527394/visual-studio-code-intellisense-stopped-to-work-on-c-sharp-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you put all the early bound classes in a namespace, so it won't mess up with your other classes. You can specify the namespace with the "/namespace:" parameter for CrmSvcUtil. I usually put the early bound classes in my DataAccess namespace, together with the crm connection classes (Service/ServiceContext wrappers).

That being said, naming your custom workflow step "Workflow" is not really the best thing to do (if that's what you did, at least so I understood). Try capturing the essence of what the step does into the name - like a title.

Comment: I am also having this same issue although i have explicitly specified the namespace but still having this problem. What could be the possible reason in this case?

Comment: And you are 100% positive it's not in the same namespace? What's the conflicting class name?

Answer (score 5):

I had two separate resource files in a same solution. Deleting one of them did the trick :P

Answer (score 2):

Just got this because I thought it would be a great idea to copy all the contents of App_Code into App_Code\bkup before deploying a change. Erm, no.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem! I guess it doesn't like new folders in certain spots.